# Antlr4/JS - what to put in the html file ? (pb following the tuto)

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4

I'm following the example in the [page about JS target](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/JavaScript+Target):
I installed require.js and antrl4 runtime on a test site, compiled my grammar as explained, prepared a small html file mimicking the tuto. (fixing the missing  after ).

For the grammar, I'm using a variant of the [Expr.g4 of the book](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/source_code).
I fixed a bug in it, extended it to doubles, adapted the actions to JS.

Now, I'm puzzled by 2 things in the html.

- the js evalution stops *at var lexer = new grammarLexer.grammarLexer(chars);* . the js console don't show the function being called. BTW I don't even understand how it could guess the function is in file grammarLexer.ls . Isn't there some require or file declaration missing here ?
- the tuto say I should write a visitor or listener, with no guidance for poor people accustomed to Antrl2 as I am. But I do have JS actions in my grammar, so isn't it sufficient in this case ? (may be "your grammar comprises production code" means exactly that).

( BTW If I have a syntax error in my js actions, will the js console show it despites the asynchronous calls ?)

But first, let unstuck point 1 :-)

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the question has now changed to "scope of funcs and tokens in the actions; how to have the java examples working in JS", so I close this question and [open a new one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296258/antlr4-js-actions-in-grammar-how-to-access-tokens-and-define-funcs-direct-in).

Answer (score 0):

ok, in the tuto a key information was missing: I do need to first do
 *var grammarLexer =require('grammarLexer'), grammarParser =require('grammarParser');* 
(how could javascript not protest on the *new grammarLexer.grammarLexer()* with the class being undefined ???)

Now it's the function call *parser.StartRule()* that never return - without any console message. ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

... got it: I just need to have a rule called StartRule (And apparently I don't need a listener).

Now the problem is in the mechanism of JS actions: in the  Expr.g4 of the book  for java target, there are functions defined in @parser::members . E.g.:

```
@parser::members {
    /** "memory" for our calculator; variable/value pairs go here */
    Map<String, Integer> memory = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    int myeval(int left, int op, int right) {
        switch ( op ) {
            case MUL : return left * right;
            case DIV : return left / right;
            case ADD : return left + right;
            case SUB : return left - right;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

that is called in the rules :

```
 e returns [int v]
    : a=e op=('*'|'/') b=e   { $v = myeval($a.v, $op.type, $b.v); }
    | a=e op=('+'|'-') b=e   { $v = myeval($a.v, $op.type, $b.v); } 
    ...
```

It perfectly works for java.
but if I translate it for JS  ( ->  function myeval(left, op, right) ) the function is not found when evaluating the rule.
-> how should this be adapted to work in a JS target, then ?
(I can uglily get it work if put in @header and replacing token by their value, but it's obviously not suppose to be the way. At least it tells that this is the last problem).

thanks,